# How to make a CardView Round

Tags: android, xml

I'm using Android Studio and I want to get in XML an Image into a CardView to make it round. On my Smartphone everything is working fine but on some Phones it's not working. Here is my code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
     android:id="@+id/card01"
     android:layout_width="74dp"
     android:layout_height="74dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     app:cardCornerRadius="74dp"
     android:shape="ring"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:innerRadius="0dp"
     android:thicknessRatio="2.0"
     android:useLevel="false"
     app:cardElevation="0dp">

          <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/profile_image1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_person_foreground" />

 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

On my Smartphone the ImageView is perfectly round but one other Phones it looks like this:
[image: Broken ImageView]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cardCornerRadius` that is exactly half of the `CardView` width/height

In your case: the  `CardView` width/height is **74dp**, so the `cardCornerRadius` will be **37dp**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
     android:id="@+id/card01"
     android:layout_width="74dp"
     android:layout_height="74dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     app:cardCornerRadius="37dp"
     android:shape="ring"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:innerRadius="0dp"
     android:thicknessRatio="2.0"
     android:useLevel="false"
     app:cardElevation="0dp">

          <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/profile_image1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_person_foreground" />

 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My sample:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the image view

```
app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="suggestedvalue"
```